# How can I do an in-memory SQL Server for integration testing?

Tags: sql-server, testing, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I want to be able to create a database and tables the same way Amazon's DynamoDb client does it but with Sql Server. Is that possible?

I'm using .net Core and this is for integration tests. Figured I can throw in the code in the fixture.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean [In-Memory OLTP (In-Memory Optimization)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/in-memory-oltp-in-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: The closest thing is to use a LocalDB instance and use a DB that you create at the start and drop at the end (slightly faster is to keep the DB and only toss the objects themselves). This is not in-memory and significantly slower than using mocks, but it's the fastest way to spin up a database that's feature-compatible (which is rather important for integration tests). Using a machine with an SSD comes recommended...

Comment: Can you be more specific about "the same way Amazon's DynamoDb client does". Do you mean NoSQL? Serverless? In Memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core [Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/):

> "The migrations feature in EF Core provides a way to incrementally
>   update the database schema to keep it in sync with the application's
>   data model while preserving existing data in the database."

[Create and Drop APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created):

> "The EnsureCreated and EnsureDeleted methods provide a lightweight
>   alternative to Migrations for managing the database schema. These
>   methods are useful in scenarios when the data is transient and can be
>   dropped when the schema changes. For example during prototyping, in
>   tests, or for local caches."

to create your tables at runtime.

And then use one of the [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) techniques:

> Data seeding is the process of populating a database with an initial
>   set of data. There are several ways this can be accomplished in EF
>   Core:
>
> - Model seed data
> - Manual migration customization
> - Custom initialization logic

to populate them with known data.

Answer (score 1):

You could start the SQL Server (at least the logfiles) on a RAM disk. and/or use delayed durability `ALTER DATABASE x SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = forced`. You could also use memory optimized tables but I think you won’t get full compatibility.

BTW: it is dangerous to use such shortcuts if your development process relies entirely on it since developers very late get feedback on bad habits and performance problems.

For that kind of volatile databases (also applies to containers) you need to add some code to your test pipeline or product tomactually create and populate the DB. (If you use containers you can think about packaging a pre-populated DB snapshot)